# How to add emoji in a spinner in an array with list items

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I want to have spinner which contains list of items in a way where every entry have an emoji with it. I have already an array but I don't know how can I add emoji's with the list items.

[image]

Comment: First from the resource put the resource in drawable and after that in the items create a list and put these drawable in the,

Comment: http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-Spinner-customized-to-show-image-and-text.htm

Comment: http://abhiandroid.com/ui/custom-spinner-examples.html

Comment: search this on google **custom spinner with image android**

Comment: Hey there! I have founded the solution to my question.. We just have to create a custom adapter class and a layout for the spinner to use , this way we will easily get a custom spinner with custom entries of our choice.. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in main activity try this code out`listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        datamodels = new ArrayList<>();
        datamodels.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera,"Girl",R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp,500, 44100,R.drawable.ic_more_vert_black_24dp,false));
        datamodels.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp,"Cave",R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp,200, 500,R.drawable.ic_more_vert_black_24dp,false));
        datamodels.add(new Model(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery,"Speaker",R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp,-9079435, 4300,R.drawable.ic_more_vert_black_24dp,false));`

After this create a model listview in your project like this and after that you should need to create a layout in xml you want.